# Different Exceptions on Python

Tags: python

I'm warming-up with the Python and need your help regarding applying a few exceptions. This is a simple guessing game that a user enters input and tries to guess the random number generated. I'm trying to catch en exception where the user enters a number from 1 to 50. 
To do so, I used IndexError. Is that the right error type I am using?

I also entered another exception, namely ValueError to prevent make sure that users enter a number, not whitespace.

My question is how can I throw an exception that the user enters a number only between 1 and 50?

```
import random

number_of_guesses = 0

number = random.randint(1,50)

name = input('Hi! Enter your name: ')


while number_of_guesses < 8:

    try:


        guess = input("Take a guess between 1 and 50 including ")

        guess = int(guess)
        number_of_guesses+=1
        guesses_left = 8 - number_of_guesses

    except IndexError:
        print('Please enter a number only between 1 and 50 including')
        continue

    except ValueError:
        print('Enter a number')
        continue


    if guess>number:
        print('Your guess is higher than the actual number',guesses_left,'guesses left')
    elif guess<number:
        print('Your guess is lower than the actual number',guesses_left,'guesses left')
    elif guess==number:
        break


if guess==number:
    print('Well done! You guessed the number in',number_of_guesses,'tries:')

if guess != number:
    print('Sorry, the number I was thinking of was',number)
```

Comment: Where were you expecting an IndexError to come from? You don't index anything.

Comment: So you think anything other than from 1 - 50 is `IndexError`?

Comment: I just edited the question for clarity. How can I throw an exception that the user enters a number only between 1 and 50?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO and python

First, take a step back to understand what the try/except block does.

`try`/`except` is a construct where Python will "try" to execute a block of code and catch any exception (or unexpected error) by matching the type of Exception with error types specified by `except` clause(s).

An `IndexError` occurs when you attempt to index an object that supports indexing (eg a `list`) and the index you have specified is outside the range of the index for example:

```py
my_list = ["a", "b", "c"]

print(mylist[0])
# will print "a"

print(my_list[4])
# with raise in IndexError as index 4 doesn't exist.
```

In your example, `ValueError` is raised by the call to `int` when a non-integer argument value is passed. Because you are not indexing anything `IndexError` is not raised.

As to placing if/else within or outside the try block. By placing it in the try block any exceptions raised in the if/else block are caught. In both cases, the behaviour of the if/else block remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

For the index error you need to index a list

```
a = [1 , 2, 3]

print(a[5])
```

With placing statements inside the try  you catch the exception(s) in your program and can handle the problem yourself so the program keeps running.

Outside the try results in an exception error and the program aborts.